# Why I can't make operations on database table? (still getting NullPointerException)

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I have a problem with saving (insert) record in database (PL/SQL) table using JPA.

Here is my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QOP_DROOLS_APP")
public class QopDroolAppModel {

        @Id //primary key
        @Column(name = "DROOL_ID")
        private Long droolId;

        @Column(name = "DROOL_NAME")
        private String droolName;

        @Column(name = "DROOL_HUMAN_NAME")
        private String droolHumanName;

        @Column(name = "DROOL_BODY")
        private String droolBody;

        @Column(name = "DROOL_DESCRIPTION")
        private String droolDescription;
}
```

Repo class

```
@Repository
public interface QopDroolAppRepo extends JpaRepository<QopDroolAppModel, Long> {}
```

DAO class

```
public class QopDroolAppDAO {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private QopDroolAppRepo repo;

    @Autowired(required = true) 
    public void saveDataInTable(String ruleName, String ruleBody, String description)
    {
        QopDroolAppModel m1 = new QopDroolAppModel();
        long generatedLong = new Random().nextInt(100);
        m1.setDroolId(generatedLong);
        m1.setDroolName(ruleName);
        m1.setDroolHumanName(ruleName);
        m1.setDroolBody(ruleBody);
        m1.setDroolDescription(description);

        this.repo.save(m1);
    }
}
```

I've tried everything but still is the same error.

> ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

UPDATE - here is stacktrace

```
2019-11-04 08:22:28 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.droolsWorkbench.services.QopDroolAppDAO.saveDataInTable(QopDroolAppDAO.java:33)
    at com.droolsWorkbench.controller.NewRuleController.DroolsRuleGenerator(NewRuleController.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your DAO class with some Spring stereotype annotation, e.g. `@Component`, so - if everything is setup properly - Spring can lookup this class, instantiate it and set dependent objects at app startup (component scanning).

```
@Component
public class QopDroolAppDAO {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private QopDroolAppRepo repo;

    public void saveDataInTable(String ruleName, String ruleBody, String description)
    {
        QopDroolAppModel m1 = new QopDroolAppModel();
        long generatedLong = new Random().nextInt(100);
        m1.setDroolId(generatedLong);
        m1.setDroolName(ruleName);
        m1.setDroolHumanName(ruleName);
        m1.setDroolBody(ruleBody);
        m1.setDroolDescription(description);
        this.repo.save(m1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added @Component to "public class QopDroolAppDAO {" and now I'm getting different error -  2019-10-31 14:40:53 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START *************************** Description: Parameter 0 of method saveDataInTable in com.droolsWorkbench.services.QopDroolAppDAO required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.

Comment: plz remove your @Autowired annotation from your `saveDataInTable` method!

Comment: I did it and NullPointerException again :/

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I've added stacktrace to the main question

Comment: I figured out that repo is null, so injection doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your class QopDroolAppDAO from a spring service / bean / application? if you dont do this then spring will not autowire your repository, which i think is whats causing your null pointer issue (repository is null and when you call .save that throws the exception

Usually you would need to set your class / service as a bean like so

```java
@Component // or @Service / @Controller depending on your application
public class QopDroolAppDAO {
```

A workaround if you dont want to make your class a spring bean would be to dependency inject your repository like so:

```java
public class QopDroolAppDAO {
    private final QopDroolAppRepo repo;

    public QopDroolAppDAO(QopDroolAppRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo
    }
```

Using this you can create your repo from within a spring bean class(service, controller component etc)

Also i would recommend against autowiring your repository in the way you did it, best practice is to inject beans through the constructor like so:

```java
@Component // or service etc
public class QopDroolAppDAO {
    private final QopDroolAppRepo repo;

    @Autowired
    public QopDroolAppDAO(QopDroolAppRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo
    }
```

read more about this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring)

Comment: I added @Component to "public class QopDroolAppDAO {" and now I'm getting different error 2019-10-31 14:40:53 ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method saveDataInTable in com.droolsWorkbench.services.QopDroolAppDAO required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.

Comment: I'm beginner in Spring so sorry if this error is trivial

Comment: ok do you have component scan in you main application? it looks like you app isnt picking up your custom spring bean, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)
Usually you will have this in your main application file (main.java etc)
ie:
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {'yoir package path here'}) // this will probably be something like com.`artifact group`.`artifact name`
public class MySpringApplication {
    
}
Note that you must use . rather than / in your component scan packages

Comment: I figured out that repo is null, so injection doesn't works